# Знаки препинания перед прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация

Никак не соображу, какой знак препинания нужно поставить в предложении такого типа: "Потому что, как сказал классик (?) "(цитата)". По идее, после "классика" должно быть двоеточие, но ведь оборот с "как" должен выделяться запятыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы смешиваете прямую речь, косвенную речь и цитирование. "Как сказал классик" - это не слова автора, а вводное предложение, поэтому двоеточие не нужно, а следует поставить запятую, а затем открыть кавычки и вставить цитату: «Потому что, как сказал классик, "русский язык велик и могуч"».